# commits form merged pull request not showing in master

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit, pull-request

I have merged a pull request to the master branch, now when I checkout to the master branch I can't see the commits done in the pull request, and I lose all work done since the creation of thee pull request. any idea why this is happening and how to get the commits to the master branch?
NOTE: in the branch which I submitted the pull request form I can see all the commits.

Comment: Where are you looking? In a local clone or in the remote where the pull request were done? Pull request is not a part of git, it is a feature implemented by services hosting git, so it would also be helpful if you told us which host (for example, github) you used to do the pull request in.

Comment: I am looking at the local clone, specifically on intellij when I'm doing a checkout to master branch, all classes I wrote in the pull request branch disappear.
I am using bitbucket stash.
@TheIceBear

Comment: If you run `git log -n 5` when having the master branch checked out, do you see the merge commit?

Comment: NO i don't. but note that the merge I have done is from the bitbucket gui, after the approval of my pull request I clicked on the merge button , which merges to master.
is there a thing that I missed when doing the merge? @TheIceBear

Comment: did you pull the master branch after the merge? The merge might have happened in the remote but you have yet to synch that to your clone by pulling the master branch in the clone.

Comment: actually no I didn't, so I should do a pull request I guess.
is this the right command?

```git pull origin master```

I'm new to git so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you have the master branch checked out, then you only need to do `git pull`